# Dynamically load data from server to "select" type input fields in datatables

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, datatables

I have a PHP code that is being called by the function loader that is only triggered on `onInitCreate` event in datatable. What I want to do is that when the user clicks the `add button` it must load the faculty Names in the `select` field.

I've already tried this code but it returns nothing or should I say a null value. I'm confident that it should return exactly one row.
This is my PHP code that gets the faculty names and return it.

**getFacultyNames.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
require_once("config.php"); 


$sql="SELECT lastName, firstName, middleName FROM table_faculty";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$stack=array();

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $name = $row[0]." ,".$row[1]." ".$row[2];
            array_push($stack,array("label" => $name, "value" => $name));
          }
echo json_encode($stack); //here it returns [{"label":"Last ,First Middle","value":"Last ,First Middle"}]
?>
```

**jquery code:**

```
function loader(){
$.ajax({
  "url": 'php/getFacultyNames.php',
  "async": false,
  "dataType": 'json',
  "success": function (json) {

         console.log( json );
         //the getFacultyNames.php is now returning correct values, 
         //but how would I be able to get the value of the json code properly?
         //it always throws an error ""parsererror" SyntaxError
         //is it proper to have a code `return json;` in this success function?
    },
    "error" : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){ console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); }

});
}
```

This is my editor initialization code:

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        "ajaxUrl": "php/table.facultyloading.php",
        "domTable": "#facultyloading",
        "events": {
            "onInitCreate":function (){
                editor.add( {
                    "label": "Assign to Faculty",
                    "name": "facultyName",
                    "type": "select",
                    "ipOpts":loader()      // Returns array of objects - .ajax() with async: false
                    });
                }
            },
        "fields": [
            {
                "label": "Subject Name",
                "name": "name",
                "type": "select",
                "ipOpts": [
                    {
                        "label": "sample",
                        "value": "sample"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Day",
                "name": "day",
                "default": "Monday",
                "type": "checkbox",
                "ipOpts": [
                    {
                        "label": "Monday ",
                        "value": "Monday "
                    },
                    {
                        "label": " Tuesday ",
                        "value": " Tuesday "
                    },
                    {
                        "label": " Wednesday ",
                        "value": " Wednesday "
                    },
                    {
                        "label": " Thursday ",
                        "value": " Thursday "
                    },
                    {
                        "label": " Friday ",
                        "value": " Friday "
                    },
                    {
                        "label": " Saturday",
                        "value": " Saturday"
                    }
                ],
                "separator": "|"
            },
            {
                "label": "Start Time",
                "name": "startTime",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "End Time",
                "name": "endTime",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "label": "Room",
                "name": "room",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    } );
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.Am I missing something? Can you help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: @bansi Thank you. I'll modify it later, but do you think that's the reason why this isn't working or it is not returning any values?

Comment: It's not the reason, it's just solid advice

Comment: @bansi, I have had a hard time spotting out where exactly OP is writing "I am using PHP 5.5.0 or above"...

Comment: @davidkonrad, what do you mean by OP?

Comment: @Harvey, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op

Comment: @Harvey Did you verify that your SQL returns data?  What value does json have?  Try adding console.log(json) to the success function.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, Sir I have inserted `console.log( json );` in the success function but in the console log I did not see anything. Does it mean that it didn't reach the success function?

Comment: @Harvey Its possible an error occurred, add the following option to your `$.ajax` function `"error" : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){ console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); }` to test for an error.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, thank you for your reply Sir. I've tried to insert the code and run it. It says `"parsererror" SyntaxError {} ` in the console. How would I be able to determine the syntax error?

Comment: @Harvey I guess that 'php/getFacultyNames.php' is not encoding the result in json properly.  Goto 'php/getFacultyNames.php' with a web browser and post the results.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, Sir I've tried to load it into a web browser. But it does not return anything? literally a blank page. What does it mean? What do you think is wrong in my php code `getFacultyNames.php`?

Comment: @Harvey Add `error_reporting(-1);` to the top of you php file to enable error reporting.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, I've edited my php code above. And `getFacultyNames.php` is already returning some values, here it is: `[["Last ,First Middle","Last ,First Middle"]]`. But in the console it says `"parsererror" SyntaxError {} `? so that it does not load in the select field. Is the json `[["Last ,First Middle","Last ,First Middle"]]` correct?

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, I tried `[["Last ,First Middle","Last ,First Middle"]]` on http://jsonlint.com/ and it says that it is a valid JSON. What do you think is the error?

Comment: @Harvey There might be something other than `echo json_encode($stack);` outputting data, possible from `require_once("config.php");`. Try changing `"dataType": 'json',` to `"dataType": 'html',`.  Make sure `console.log( json );` is still in your success function.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, It does not have an error anymore. But in the select field it loads this value `<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\civil\php\php\config.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
[["Last ,First Middle","Last ,First Middle"]]`. And in the php `getFacultyNames.php` it also returns the same.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist, What I want to do with the json `[["Last ,First Middle","Last ,First Middle"]]` is to convert it like this `{"label": "Last ,First Middle", "value":"Last ,First Middle"}` for the select field to be able to load it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've converted the mysql function to `PDO_MySQL` and finally it works this is my new `getFacultyNames.php` and I've also modified my jquery code a bit. Thanks for all your help! :)

**getFacultyNames.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
require_once("config.php"); 
$stack=array();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT lastName, firstName, middleName FROM table_faculty");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $row['lastName']." ,".$row['firstName']." ".$row['middleName'];
    array_push($stack,array($name,$name));
  }

  echo json_encode($stack);
}
?>
```

**jquery code**

```
function names(){       
    var test= new Array({"label" : "a", "value" : "a"});
    test.splice(0,1);
        $.ajax({
          "url": 'php/getFacultyNames.php',
          "async": false,
          "dataType": 'json',
          "success": function (json) {
              for(var a=0;a < json.length;a++){
                obj= { "label" : json[a][0], "value" : json[a][1]};
                test.push(obj);
              }
            },
          "error" : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){ console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); }

        });
        return test;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `die` to end of `getFacultyNames.php`.

```
 echo json_encode($stack);
 die;
```

**UPDATE**
Try to remove `"dataType": 'json'` and set in callbaks:

```
   try {
     json = JSON.parse(data);
   }
   catch (e) {
     console.log("Parse error:"+e);
   };
```

Comment: I've added die but the same error I get. `"parsererror" 
SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Harvey see in console respone (what server return ).Trouble in getFacultyNames.php.

Comment: I've inserted the above code inside the success function, remove `"dataType": 'json'` and run it. In the console it says `Parse error:ReferenceError: data is not defined `.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function loader(){
  var responseText = $.ajax({
    "url": 'php/getFacultyNames.php',
    "async": false,
    "dataType": null,
    "error" : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){ 
             console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); 
     }
   }).responseText;

  return $.parseJSON(responseText)
}
```

This will do the AJAX call and return you the properly formatted JSON object.